# Windows batch file to automatically zipping the files

Tags: batch-file

```
for /D %%A in (*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%%A.zip" -xr!*.bat "%%A" -r -x!*.xls
```

The above batch file is zipping all files in a folder automatically using 7-zip software.

My question is: suppose I have a 3 folders in a directory named as "1", "2" and "3" .. under this folder. I have pdf files named as "apple", "ball" and "cat" respectively.

If I unzip any one of the folder,It unzips the "1" folder. 
I don't want "1" to be zipped. I want to zip the sub-folders and sub-files in "1.zip".

For example if I unzip "1.zip", it should unzip only apple.pdf, It should not unzip "1" folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /D %%A in (*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip ".\%%A.zip" -xr!*.bat "%%A\*" -r -x!*.xls
```

Add a relative reference to the content of the initial directory `.\%%A\*` to not include the directory into filenames